# Azure mobile apps CRUD operations on SQL table (node.js backend)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

This is my first post here so please don't get mad if my formatting is a bit off ;-)
I'm trying to develop a backend solution using Azure mobile apps and node.js for server side scripts. It is a steep curve as I am new to javaScript and node.js coming from the embedded world. What I have made is a custom API that can add users to a MSSQL table, which is working fine using the tables object. However, I also need to be able to delete users from the same table. My code for adding a user is:

```
var userTable = req.azureMobile.tables('MyfUserInfo');
item.id = uuid.v4();

userTable.insert(item).then( function (){
    console.log("inserted data");
    res.status(200).send(item);
});
```

It works. The Azure node.js documentation is really not in good shape and I keep searching for good example on how to do simple things. Pretty annoying and time consuming.
The SDK documentation on delete operations says it works the same way as read, but that is not true. Or I am dumb as a wet door. My code for deleting looks like this - it results in exception

```
query = queries.create('MyfUserInfo')
        .where({ id: results[i].id });

userTable.delete(query).then( function(delet){
console.log("deleted id ", delet);
});
```

I have also tried this and no success either

```
userTable.where({ id: item.id }).read()
        .then( function(results) {
        if (results.length > 0) 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                userTable.delete(results[i].id);
                });
            }
        }
```

Can somebody please point me in the right direction on the correct syntax for this and explain why it has to be so difficult doing basic stuff here ;-) It seems like there are many ways of doing the exact same thing, which really confuses me.
Thanks alot
Martin

Answer (score 2):

You could issue SQL in your api

```
var api = {
get: (request, response, next) => {
    var query = {
        sql: 'UPDATE TodoItem SET complete=@completed',
        parameters: [
            { name: 'completed', value: request.params.completed }
        ]
    };

    request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
    .then(function (results) {
        response.json(results);
    });
}};
module.exports = api;
```

That is from their sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/samples/custom-api-sql-stmt/api/completeall.js)
Here is the full list of [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples) to take a look at

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a custom API for a table?  Just define the table within the tables directory and add any custom authorization / authentication.

Comment: As I understood it if I add the table in the tables directory, it can only be used through the endpoint www.website.com/tables/<tablename>, which is not what I want. I want to execute a custom API and from there operate on the table

Comment: Let me rephrase. I added the table under /tables but I don't want to manipulate the table through www.website.com/tables/<tablename>. I want to have this controlled in my business logic, not in the android app client

Comment: Understood.  A custom API that references another module with shared logic would be the way to go here.  You can pass req.azureMobile.tables object to get the table reference.