# Azure Mobile Apps CRUD Operations syntax

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

this is my first time using SO. i came here because i recently migrated to the new Microsoft Azure App Service and it appears that the node.js syntax etc. has been changed or is a little different. This is my current code with the old mobile service and i wish to migrate to the new syntax. there are very limited references in terms of whats change etc. and i couldn't find much on google either.

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
var table = tables.getTable('user');
table.where({ 
   userid: item.userid
}).read({
   success: upsertItem
});


function upsertItem(existingItems) {
    if (existingItems.length > 0) {
        item.id = existingItems[0].id;
        table.update(item, {
        success: function(updatedItem) {
        request.respond(200, updatedItem)
        }
      });
    } else {
        request.execute();
    }
 }
```

}

This isa sample of the new script

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();

table.read(function (context) {
 return context.execute();
});
```

ive also seen this post but its not helpful

[Azure mobile apps CRUD operations on SQL table (node.js backend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998562/azure-mobile-apps-crud-operations-on-sql-table-node-js-backend)

my objective is to perform UPSERT as per my original code. If you can help me out by providing the exact conversion, that would be my preferred answer.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can leverage the [`use()`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_express_tables_table.html#~use) to custom your own middleware to handle additional operations.

As Insert operation implements with HTTP POST requests. you can refer to [Azure Mobile Apps - An item to insert was not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426765/azure-mobile-apps-an-item-to-insert-was-not-provided/38428030#38428030) for how to implement a post request with data in POSTMAN against Azure Mobile Apps.

And then, you can install `body-parser` module in your Azure Mobile Apps to parse request body.

add following code in `app.js` to enable the module:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
```

At last, please consider the following code snippet in Easy Tables Script about how to use middleware:

```
var insertMiddleware = function(req,res,next){
    var queries = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/query');
    var t = req.azureMobile.tables('TodoItem');
    var query = queries.create('TodoItem')
            .where({ text: req.body.text });
    t.read(query).then(function(data){
      if(data.length === 0){
        next();
      }else{
        data.text = "something new";
        console.log(data);
        var query = {
            sql: 'UPDATE TodoItem SET text = @text where id = @id',
            parameters: [
                { name: 'text', value: data.text },
                { name: 'id', value: data.id }
            ]
        };
        req.azureMobile.data.execute(query).then(function(result){
          res.status(200).json("success");
        });
      }
    });
};
table.insert.use(insertMiddleware, table.operation);
table.insert(function (context) {
  return context.execute();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a complete series on the new Node.js SDK here: https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/

There is also the official documentation and that is fairly comprehensive: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/

There is also a compatibility package that is designed to make it easier by converting your old service to the new format:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mobile-apps-compatibility

Between these, you should be able to easily convert your site to the new Azure Mobile Apps SDK.